# JQUERY: can't support IE 11 and firefox 50.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

please kindly advice, the below coding can't support IE 11 and firefox ver 50.1, but it can work at chrome ver 55.0 as well..
this coding should be export my data from jsp to excel, my firefox and IE without error in console, after press the button, it not export my data to excel. my chrome is working without error.
what's wrong for my coding....

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

 <script src="../jQuerylib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../jQuerylib/jquery.base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myButtonControlID").click(function(e) {
          var dt = new Date();
          var year = dt.getFullYear().toString();
          var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
          var day = dt.getDate();
          var hour = dt.getHours();
          var mins = dt.getMinutes();

          var postfix = year +  month +  day + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
          var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
          var table_div = document.getElementById('MyTable');
          var table_html = table_div.innerHTML .replace(/ /g, '%20');
          a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
          //setting the file name
           a.download = 'JDC_mon_' + postfix + '.xls';
          //triggering the function
          a.click();
          //just in case, prevent default behaviour
          e.preventDefault();

      });
    });
```

thanks

Comment: You need to clarify. What exactly is the wrong behavior that you encounter in IE and Chrome? And which versions? Can you give us the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: firefox and presumably IE wont allow you to execute `a.click()` unless the `a` tag is added to the DOM

Comment: please kindly advise what mean for a tag is added to the DOM ? sorry, for this i not very familiar...

Comment: `<a>` is an anchor **tag** ... the DOM is the Document Object Model ... it's basically the web page ... creating a tag doesn't add it to the page ... you have to add it to the page for this to work in firefox at least